# método o función para subir y renombrar imagen en php

Tags: php, funciones, imagen, método

Hola amigos resulta que tengo este código que me hice en una anterior aplicación, pero resulta que la que estoy haciendo ahora es con programación orientada a objetos. Y no se como convertir este código en una función o método.

```php
    $nombreTemporal = $_FILES['afile']['tmp_name'];
        $cadena = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuwwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQVWXYZ1234567";
        $longitud = strlen($cadena);
        $archivo=$_FILES['afile']['name'];
        $nombreFinal="i";
        $extension = explode(".",$archivo);
        $ext = $extension[1];//AQUI LA EXTENSION
        for($i=0; $i<=6; $i++){
            $aleatorio = rand(1, $longitud);
            $caracter = substr($cadena, $aleatorio, 1);
            $nombreFinal.= $caracter;
        }
        $nombreFinal.= ".";
        $nombreFinal.= $ext;
        move_uploaded_file($nombreTemporal, 'uploads/'.$nombreFinal);
```

El método o función  quedaría mas o menos así:

```php
 public function getSubirNombrarImagen($imagen){

     $imagen // en esta variable iría la imagen subida desde el formulario 

}




    }

    }
```

Digamos que no se como tratar el paso de la variable $imagen(donde irá la imagen desde formulario como parámetro) a la función y poderla tratar con la variable array :   $nombreTemporal = $_FILES['afile']['tmp_name']

Gracias por vuestra ayuda no busco que se me haga el código solo una orientación.

Comment: Por que no haces que la funcion reciba como parametro `$_FILES` algo `getSubirNombrarImagen($files)` luego dentro de la funcion en lugar de trabajar con `$_FILES` trabajas con `$files`

Comment: Porque precisamente no se luego como incorporar  $_FILES['afile']['tmp_name'] despues de tomar como parámetro $files en la función getSubirNombrarImagen($files). No se como tratar $files con $_FILES['afile']['tmp_name'] después de tomar $files como parámetro.

Comment: Pues esactamente igual, en lugar de `$_FILES['afile']['tmp_name']` harias `$files['afile']['tmp_name']` dentro de la funcion. Si le pasas $_FILES directamente en $files sera una copia

Comment: ok, gracias por tu ayuda voy a probarlo a ver.